# SQLite unix epoch conversion

Tags: sqlite

I have two rows in my SQLite database, with timestamps for Saturday February 7th, and Friday March 6th.

I am running this query:

```
select strftime('%w', datetime(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch')),
       datetime(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch'),
       CreationDate from mytable
```

Output is:

```
"6" "2015-03-07 02:17:02"   "1425694622000"
"6" "2015-02-07 05:00:00"   "1423285200000"
```

So clearly something is wrong, it's saying both these timestamps are on Saturday. I assume the problem is that i'm dividing my timestamp by 1000 before casting it to the unix epoch and datetime doesn't like this?

What would be a recommendation to get back the correct date in datetime? I really need to store things in milliseconds not some other time.

Comment: `1425694622000 / 1000` is March 7th, 2015 *in UTC*.  Perhaps you're being confused by time zones?  I have updated my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct, Feb 7, 2015 and March 7, 2015 are both Saturday.  Remember, non-leap-year February has 28 days which divides evenly into 7 day weeks, so March dates will have the same days of the week.

```
$ cal 2015
                             2015

      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10   8  9 10 11 12 13 14   8  9 10 11 12 13 14
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  15 16 17 18 19 20 21  15 16 17 18 19 20 21
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
25 26 27 28 29 30 31                        29 30 31
```

You may be getting confused by time zones.  [Unix time is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  By default [SQLite date functions will use the UTC time zone](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).  If you want your times in the local time zone, you have to tell SQLite that.

```
sqlite> select strftime('%w', datetime(1425694622000 / 1000, 'unixepoch'));
6
sqlite> select strftime('%w', datetime(1425694622000 / 1000, 'unixepoch'), "localtime");
5
```

It can be done by either datetime or strftime.  I picked strftime because time zones complicate everything so I want to add it as late as possible in the formatting stage.

Comment: Thank you so much - really grateful for your help on this matter. this was precisely the issue at hand.